# How to set background color of splashscreen in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using React Native to create an Android app, using Android Studio and an emulator. I'm working on it's splashscreen first but I'm having trouble putting color behind the logo of the app. The picture being used is 193 x 192 with 96 DPI.

[File layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HThfT.png)

[launch_screen.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZWJP.png)

[colors.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z7pI.png)

[styles.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaSxb.png)

[splash screen image with gray on top and bottom within emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igerl.png)

I've tried setting

`<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blue</item>`

in styles.xml but that changes the wrong thing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `launch_screen.xml` file's Relative Layout, you need to add background  prop like `android:background="@color/blue"`.

So, it will look like this,

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/blue">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works in Expo in app.json

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#backgroundcolor

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "splash": {
      "image": "./app/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).